# sql query to select count of only max value from table

Tags: php, mysql

```
partyname    state        constituency     candidatename   district    votes

BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-East     Nitin Gadkari   Nagpur       1200
AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-East     Arvind Kejriwal Nagpur       750
BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-West     Vicky           Nagpur       4800
AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-West     Lucky           Nagpur       3500
BJP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-North    Rakesh          Nagpur       100
AAP       Maharashtra   Nagpur-North    Ravan          Nagpur       1500
```

below is my expected output for above table

query select only max vlue from votes group by partyname and constituency and display like below output.

```
partyname       Count

BJP          2

AAP          1
```

**bcoz bjp leads from nagpur -east and nagpur west**

**so it display count 2**

**and aap leads from nagpur - north then it display only 1 count.**

plz suggest me query......

Comment: can you provide struture and sample data in sql fiddle

Comment: i have crate all the table schema and data on fiddle...plz help..

Comment: provided answer with sql fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select max(votes) from tableName group by constituency
```

Sql fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceb017/1

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need one join to get the maximum number of votes, and then another to get the party name and count of wins:

```
select c.partyname, count(*) as numwins
from constituency c join
     (select constituency, max(votes) as maxvotes
      from constituency c
      group by constituency
     ) cm
     on c.constituency = cm.constituency and c.votes = cm.votes
group by c.partyname;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT STATE FROM CONSTITUENCY
GROUP BY STATE
HAVING COUNT(STATE) = (
SELECT MAX(COUNTS) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) COUNTS
FROM CONSTITUENCY
GROUP BY STATE) COUNTER
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).